# magento 2 setup install database error

Tags: magento2

> sudo ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1:8500
>   --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password=1234 --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1

After running above command it shows following error

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method
>   unknown   to the client
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]     Parameter validation failed

Comment: did you use correct DB password at `--db-password`?

Comment: yes
i can establish connection via mysql workbench as well as from terminal  
@kunj

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

> sudo ./magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1:8500"
>   --db-user="root" --db-password="1234" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento2"   --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="admin@admin.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --backend-frontname="admin" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1"

This is the one which works for me, hopefully it will work for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command, I use this personally use this command :

```
sudo bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://marketplcae.local --db-host=localhost --db-name=marketplace  --db-user=admin --db-password="admin123" --admin-lastname=zeshan --admin-firstname=shoukat --admin-email=zeeshan.hamza5867@gmail.com --admin-password=admin123  --admin-user=admin  --language=en_US --currency=GBP --timezone=Europe/London
```